# Where can I find the web app for designing Robot Turtles boards?

Tags: robot-turtles

I once heard about a web app for designing Robot Turtles boards. Where is that?

Comment: Recommendations for web apps are off-topic.

Comment: Robot Turtles is not a web app. http://www.robotturtles.com/

Comment: @AndrewVandever, I used to work for Google. This question was posted almost a year ago when finding Robot Turtles resources was more difficult. Moreover, that search doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's funny, I didn't notice it was such an old question. Who the heck finds old questions and decides to flag them? It does answer the question, though. The top result is (appropriately) http://www.robotturtles.com/mazes/, which describes and links to the app you were looking for.

Comment: @AndrewVandever, the answer I provided is a more direct answer.

Comment: Anyway, the questions *is* about a board game. Can the 'on hold' status be taken off?

Comment: I agree on both points, and went ahead and tossed you a reopen vote. :)

Comment: @AndrewVandever The reason this got flagged after so long was that there is a [meta topic](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1254/3389) to add tags to untagged questions and this one was reviewed as part of that.

Comment: @AndrewVandever _"Who the heck finds old questions and decides to flag them?"_ You seem dumbfounded by this activity, but it's fine and an ordinary part of Stack Exchange site moderation. Anyone who comes across an old question that doesn't fit our current standards can flag or vote for closure, and it'll get closed if other people agree it doesn't fit our current standards. It is not a disruptive activity, and a good part of maintaining site quality. If you find old questions that don't fit our current standards, please do flag or vote for closure.

Comment: @doppelgreener Fair enough. I've been more disruptive than anybody on this thread, so I'm sorry about that. I do think that the close votes are unwarranted and reopen is the better choice in this case. Is there a meta topic about supplemental apps? I tried searching for "supplement" and "app", and didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: @Thunderforge, I've tagged the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That web application exists at http://maze-builder.robotturtles.com/.